# WSO2 Carbon: An error has occured while accessing backend services

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

We have a big issue using WSO2 ESB, which could be a reason to go with another BUS.

Sometimes, without any reason, WSO2 stops working. It is not possible insert anything into it.
Normally you obtain a blank page as result of your try. But if you are lucky, the system could return this:

> WSO2 Carbon: An error has occured while accessing backend services.

We have try to install a completely new WSO2 ESB without any relation with our WSO2 ESB. We have try to restart the server who stores it and install every app from the beginning, and it gets the same issue.

However, 2 or 3 days later, it is resolved by itself... no reason...
So we cannot be having this issue every week and wait 2 or 3 days to recover our work.

Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: Which ESB version you are using? What do you mean by insert anything? And, which operation causes the blank page?

Answer (score 0):

It maybe the issue I mentioned here - [WSO2ESB 4.8.1 PassThroughHttpSender does not return thread to worker pool on exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510392/wso2esb-4-8-1-passthroughhttpsender-does-not-return-thread-to-worker-pool-on-exc) the result of it is exactly the same. ESB stops processing any incoming connection because there are no available "worker" threads.